# How to change the anchor value in MDFloatingActionButtonSpeedDial in KivyMD?

Tags: python, button, kivy-language

I have been working with kivymd to develop a mobile application.   But I was having a problem regarding MDFloatingActionButtonSpeedDial.   I wanted to set the anchor value in MDFloatingActionButtonSpeedDial to "**left**" for some buttons and "**right**" for some buttons.   So I modified the class of **MDFloatingActionButtonSpeedDial** that is in the module "**kivymd.uix.button**" and added some more options in '**anchor**' which assumes OptionProperty.   Along with it I also added the methods required for the applied changes.   The changes in acnhor are:-

```
anchor = OptionProperty('right',option=["right","left"])
```

And the changes in the methods are:-

```
def set_pos_labels(self, widget):
    """Sets the position of the floating labels."""

    if self.anchor == "right":
        widget.x = Window.width - widget.width - dp(86)
    
    elif self.anchor == "left":
        widget.x = widget.width + dp(86)
    

def set_pos_root_button(self, instance):
    """Sets the position of the root button."""

    if self.anchor == "right":
        instance.y = dp(20)
        instance.x = Window.width - (dp(56) + dp(20))
        
    elif self.anchor == "left":
        instance.y = dp(20)
        instance.x = (dp(56) + dp(20))

def set_pos_bottom_buttons(self, instance):
    """Sets the position of the bottom buttons in a stack."""

    if self.anchor == "right":
        if self.state != "open":
            instance.y = instance.height / 2
        instance.x = Window.width - (instance.height + instance.width / 2)
        
    elif self.anchor == "left":
        if self.state != "open":
            instance.y = instance.height / 2
        instance.x = (instance.height + instance.width / 2)
```

I have added the left anchor property as the right anchor was present by default.

The Builder string that I have written is as follows:-

```
MDFloatingActionButtonSpeedDial:
     data : app.data_download
     rotation_root_button : True
     id : download_button
     icon: 'download'
     anchor: 'left'
                    
                    
MDFloatingActionButtonSpeedDial:
      data : app.data_return
      rotation_root_button: True
      icon : 'arrow-left'
      anchor: 'right'
```

Now whenever I tried to set the anchor property to 'left' other than the default option(right) in my builder string file the program returns an error.   I want to inform if I set the default value of anchor to left then I get the error for setting the anchor to right and when I set the default value of anchor to right then I get the error for setting the anchor to left. The error that that I am getting is:-

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 700, in _apply_rule
 setattr(widget_set, key, value)
 File "kivy\weakproxy.pyx", line 35, in kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.__setattr__
 File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 497, in kivy.properties.Property.__set__
 File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 541, in kivy.properties.Property.set
 File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 532, in kivy.properties.Property.set
 File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 1252, in kivy.properties.OptionProperty.check
 ValueError: MDFloatingActionButtonSpeedDial.anchor is set to an invalid option 'left'. Must be one 
 of: []

 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "onlinecv2.py", line 500, in <module>
 ScanIt().run()
 File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 829, in run
 root = self.build()
 File "onlinecv2.py", line 435, in build
 camerascreen    = Builder.load_string(screen_helper)
 File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 405, in load_string
 rule_children=rule_children)
 File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 707, in _apply_rule
 e), cause=tb)
 kivy.lang.builder.BuilderException: Parser: File "<inline>", line 154:
 ...
     152:                        id : download_button
     153:                        icon: 'download'
 >>  154:                        anchor: 'left'
     155:
     156:
 ...
 ValueError: MDFloatingActionButtonSpeedDial.anchor is set to an invalid option 'left'. Must be one 
 of: []
 File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 700, in _apply_rule
 setattr(widget_set, key, value)
 File "kivy\weakproxy.pyx", line 35, in kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.__setattr__
 File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 497, in kivy.properties.Property.__set__
 File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 541, in kivy.properties.Property.set
 File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 532, in kivy.properties.Property.set
 File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 1252, in kivy.properties.OptionProperty.check
```

The output that I am getting (which is undesirable) when i dont set any anchor value in my kivy file is as:-
[I only get the floating button in the right. But the output that I desire is I wanted two floating buttons to be present on both side of the screen i.e. left as well as right. But I am getting only on one side and so i started to change the module but ended up with an error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhB4a.jpg)

So, I would be glad if you can provide me an solution to solve this error so that I can use both the anchor properties 'left' and 'right'.

Answer (score 0):

When you use multiple options in **OptionProperty**, you should use `options` instead of `option`

`anchor = OptionProperty("right, options=("left", "right"))`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).